# How to notify ViewModel on a change in Model (EntityObject) calculated property

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, viewmodel

I have added a calculated property to my Model (Entity Framework autogenerated class). **How do I notify the ViewModel of any changes on this property**? The calculated property sits in my partial class so the class is an EntityObject.

The EF EntityObject class has ReportPropertyChanged on every autogenerated property but how do I do it with my own calculated properties? If I try to use it, I get an ArgumentException: The property 'xxxxxx' does not have a valid entity mapping on the entity object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, you have extended an EF entity to add a calculated property and you want to update the UI accordingly when your calculated property changes.

In that case, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your partial class and then call `OnPropertyChanged("propertyName")` when your calculated property is updated.